# SQLBase usage in a Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, sqlbase

I am trying to connect to a Grupta SQLBase Database via my Java application.

I searched through the web but all I could find is that there is a need of an SQlBaseJDBC jar that works as a bridge but I am unable to download it.

Can you provide any alternatives or a place where I can download this driver? Has someone worked with this driver in the past and can comment on it?

Also, can I use the JdbcToODBC driver provided by sun to connect to this database? Grupta provides a guide where there is the option to connect to their database through an ODBC driver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLBaseJDBC.jar ships with SQLBase as standard ( At least for v12.1 ). You dont need to download it - it will already be in the run-time folder for SQLBase.
If you are running SQLBase 9 or v10 you can download a Driver pack here: [SQLbase driver Packs v9 or v10](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/SQLBase_Driver_Packs)
Alternatively connect to SQLBase using ODBC no-problem. What specifically do you want to know.

Comment: Hi Steve and thank you for your response. Sorry for replying late. What I am trying to do is communicate with an SQLBase Database through my Java Program. For a normal ODBC database I would need a JDBCtoODBC bridge(e.g. the suns one) to run a SQL command. Does the same apply with SQLBase? Can I use this Bridge to communicate with the SQLBase database? Also are there any known issues with the SQLBase to JDBC bridge? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Rather than give loads of bits here that may not be relevant to you, you may be best to either:
 1) Search the old Gupta User Group forum for 'JDBC' or similar here: [Old Gupta User Group Forum](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/search.php?keywords=JDBC) ( there is about 10 pages of info. relating to this )
OR
2) Search and/or Post on the New Gupta User Group forum here: [New Gupta User Group Forum](http://forum.tdcommunity.net/index.php)

Note you can't post questions on the Old site, but you can on the New site, if you cant find what you need, and would like to communicate with other Java bodies.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Earlier you mentioned the driver pack for SQLBase 9 and 10 . We identified that the version of SQLBase is 11.7.4. Can you please tell me where can I find the SQLBaseJDBC.jar? Does it ships as a standard or should I download it ?

Comment: It ships as standard - but you need to explicitly select it at instal time to have it . If it is not in your SQLBase run-time folder , then you'll need to download.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the SQLBaseJDBC.jar is an installation option - you choose to instal it or not when SB is installed. You actually now need an OpenText support contract to be able to download bits like this if it isnt installed already ( I know - they dont make it easy ) . Here is a link to the online SQLBase manual for v9 - **See Chapter 9** [SQLBase  Connectivity v9](https://support.guptatechnologies.com/Docs/SQLBase/Books/connecting/index.htm#connecting_general_intro.htm)  , which details where to find it if installed ( it still apllies to v11  - although the driver has been upgraded a lot since then ) and also other info that may be relevant. Alternatively here is a link directly to the driver [SQLBase JDBC Driver](https://www.dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/SqlBaseJdbcDriver.zip).
I do have a v11 manual detailing lots of JDBC info. , but its not online so can't get it to you here. 
Or , you can download a trial version of SQLBase 11.7 and get the Documentation and driver here: [SQLBase Trial Version with documentation / JDBC driver](https://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-sqlbase)

Comment: Great response Steve. Thank you very much. If I download the driver for version 12.1.1 (the one you provided) will this work for v11.7.4 as well? Or should I download the trial version and get the driver? Also one last question, can I use the JDBCtoODBC driver provided by sun to establish the connection?